# SQL - How to output a result set with a binary indicator if something is true?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
users (id,name)
items (id,title)
users_items (user_id,item_id)
```

`users` and `items` should be pretty self explanatory. `users_items` holds whether a user has "favourited" an item. So if user with id 5 has favourited item with id 7, the users_items table will hold the record (5,7) for user_id and item_id respectively.

I want to be able to output all items, but state next to each one, whether the currently logged in user has favourited that item.

Obviously, I could just get all the items and then loop over them and do a separate mysql call to see if any rows are returned from users_items with the relevant user id and lesson id, but is there a nicer way to do this in 1 function. Maybe with some fancy join?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM items LEFT JOIN users_items ON items.id=users_items.item_id AND user_id=1 -- change user_id
```

In PHP, the next step would be to just check whether it evaluates as true or not:

```
if ($row['item_id'])
{
    // Yes
}
else {
    // No
}
```

Comment: Some really good answers, but this seems the most elegant and does exactly what I want. Thanks. I'll mark it as the correct answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN users_items ui on ui.user_id=i.id  and ui.id = curUserId
```

Comment: This will not give all the items. This would only give the favorite items

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.id, i.name, count(ui.item_id) 
from items i
left outer users_items ui on i.id = ui.item_id
    and ui.user_id = 123
group by i.id, i.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT I.*, CASE WHEN UI.item_id IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END FavouritedByUser
FROM items I
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT item_id
            FROM users_items 
            WHERE user_id = @CurrentUser) UI
ON I.id = UI.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CASE` for this.

```
SELECT i.*, CASE WHEN ui.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Item i
LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Item ui on ui.item_id = i.id AND ui.user_id = current_user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, 
    CASE WHEN ui.item_id IS NOT NULL 
        THEN 'Favorite' 
    ELSE 'Not Favorite'
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN users_items ui ON ui.item_id = i.id
WHERE ui.user_id = some_variable;
```